# Django Admin app: building a dynamic list of admin actions

Tags: python, django, closures

I am trying to dynamically build a list of admin actions using the [`get_actions()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_actions) method on a `ModelAdmin`. Each action relates to a particular instance of another model, and as new instances may be added or removed, I want to make sure the list of actions reflects that.

Here's the `ModelAdmin`:

```
class PackageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'quality')

    def _actions(self, request):
        for q in models.Quality.objects.all():
            action = lambda modeladmin, req, qset: qset.update(quality=q)
            name = "mark_%s" % (q,)
            yield (name, (action, name, "Mark selected as %s quality" % (q,)))

    def get_actions(self, request):
        return dict(action for action in self._actions(request))
```

(The weird repetitive dict of tuples return value is explained by the [Django docs for `get_actions()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_actions).)

As expected, this results in a list of appropriately named admin actions for bulk assignment of `Quality` foreign keys to `Package` objects.

**The problem** is that whichever action I choose, the same `Quality` object gets assigned to the selected `Package`s.

I assume that the closures I am creating with the `lambda` keyword all contain a reference to the same `q` object, so every iteration changes the value of `q` for *every function*.

**Can I break this reference, allowing me to still use a list of closures containing different values of `q`?**

---

Edit: I realise that `lambda` is not necessary in this example. Instead of:

```
action = lambda modeladmin, req, qset: qset.update(quality=q)
```

I could simply use `def`:

```
def action(modeladmin, req, qset):
    return qset.update(quality=q)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
   def make_action(quality):
        return lambda modeladmin, req, qset: qset.update(quality=quality)

   for q in models.Quality.objects.all():
       action = make_action(q)
       name = "mark_%s" % (q,)
       yield (name, (action, name, "Mark selected as %s quality" % (q,)))
```

if that doesn't work, i suspect the bug has something to do with your use of `yield`.  maybe try:

```
def make_action(quality):
    name = 'mark_%s' % quality
    action = lambda modeladmin, req, qset: qset.update(quality=quality)
    return (name, (action, name, "Mark selected as %s quality" % quality))

def get_actions(self, request):
    return dict([make_action for q in models.Quality.objects.all()])
```

Comment: Thanks, I had just hit upon a solution similar to your second suggestion and was about to post when I read this. +1 for your time.

Comment: I'm struggling to get this working. Could you post the complete working example for this?

Comment: Ah. sussed it:
(edit - no code formatting in comments! bummer...)
`    def get_actions(self, request):
        def make_action(quality):
            name = 'mark_%s' % quality
            action = lambda modeladmin, req, qset: qset.update(quality=quality)
            return (name, (action, name, "Mark selected as %s quality" % quality))
        return dict(make_action(q) for q in models.Quality.objects.all())
`

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in my comment to andylei's answer, I just found a solution; using another function to create the closure seems to break the reference, meaning that now every action refers to the correct instance of `Quality`.

```
def create_action(quality):
    fun = lambda modeladmin, request, queryset: queryset.update(quality=quality)
    name = "mark_%s" % (quality,)
    return (name, (fun, name, "Mark selected as %s quality" % (quality,)))

class PackageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'quality')

    def get_actions(self, request):
        return dict(create_action(q) for q in models.Quality.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that q stays the same object within the loop.

Does it work with `quality=q.id` in your lambda?

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this doesn't solve the problem. I guess `q.id` in the lambda is still being passed by reference.