# give a category using the action in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

can I use django actions to give a category to my articles in django-admin?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155, db_index=True)

class Woman(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', blank=True)
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True)
```

How can i create an action with the help of which it will be possible to give categories for several articles.
I mean something like that, but i need 'Mark as "name of category" ' instead of 'Delete selected users'
I hope you guys understand me, I don't know how explain it better

[image]

(Its not my screenshot, just took it form documentation for greater understanding)

Comment: `Woman` is an article? It is not entirely clear *what* you aim to do.

Comment: woman is an article and it has categories using foreignkey, i wanna give a category to my articles in django-admin with django actions but have no ideas how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I assume it's possible.. but it won't be dynamic like I assume you want it

This would be a way

#### admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Category, Women

@admin.action(description='Mark selected as Category 1') # <- text of the dropdown
def set_cat_1(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    # action to do:
    queryset.update(cat=Category.objects.get(pk=1))

@admin.action(description='Mark selected as Category 2')
def set_cat_2(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(cat=Category.objects.get(pk=2))

class WomenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'cat']
    ordering = ['title']
    actions = [set_cat_1, set_cat_2,]

admin.site.register(Women, WomenAdmin)
```

When you add a new Category you'll have to add a new action + add it to the admin's action list.

---

There possibly might be a way do have it dynamic, but it's not immediately clear if that's a reasonable option

#### Edit:

This might possibly be a dynamic option, definitely not from the Docs; it's pretty wild imo.
I just ripped + changed it from this: [Django Admin app: building a dynamic list of admin actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902332/django-admin-app-building-a-dynamic-list-of-admin-actions)
I'd be interested to hear if this works

###### admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Category, Women

class WomenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'cat']
    ordering = ['title']

    def make_action(category):
        name = 'mark_%s' % category
        action = lambda modeladmin, req, qset: qset.update(cat=category)
        return (name, (action, name, "Mark selected as %s" % category))

    def get_actions(self, request):
        return dict([make_action for c in Category.objects.all()])

admin.site.register(Women, WomenAdmin)
```

It might possibly remove your default actions.. So if you still want those try something like:

```py
def get_actions(self, request):
    actions = super().get_actions(request)
    actions.update(dict([make_action for c in Category.objects.all()]))
    return actions
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped. I also made an edit with supposedly a dynamic way of doing it, so that might be worth a shot!- if you try it let me know if it works!